# How to get bluetooth setting values

Tags: android, bluetooth, settings

This turns out to be harder than I thought. In settings of android, user can select a bluetooth device for connection to the phone. How can I get the setting value(s)?

I know I can get a list of paired devices and try to connect each device with code. But  I wonder if there is any other way to get the setting value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting default bluetooth adapter object and explore it?

Getting default bluetooth adapter :

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

API to explore what can you do with BluetoothAdapter object : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199482/finding-android-bluetooth-paired-devices) If you can any Help

And Here [Simple Android and Java Bluetooth Application](http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/) and **[source code](https://github.com/luugiathuy/Remote-Bluetooth-Android/downloads)** also.