# getbondeddevices() not returning paired bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to enumerate all paired bluetooth devices with my device.  In settings I can view the paired devices, but the following code does not return any items:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDeviceSet = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199482/finding-android-bluetooth-paired-devices) and other posts that use this method, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have the following permissions in Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Furthermore, if I put one of the paired devices into discovery mode, and scan, then the device comes back as paired.  If I check:

```
device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED
```

from the scan, it returns true.

What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is completely correct. I have the exact same thing in my app and I never got any complain from any user that this feature does not work. Please check for other parts of your app. Below is the snippet of my app that does the same thing, and I have the same permission as you described.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
} else {
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add("No Paired Device.");
}
```

Comment: I am happy to hear that. May I ask what the problem was?

Comment: Certainly - I was trying to display in a list which requires conversion to an ArrayList - that was failing to convert correctly.

Comment: @Kasra how to identify connected device & paired devices ? I have to connect multiple device even if one of them is disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure bluetooth state is enabled before starting your `Activity`

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
}
```