# Android Studio - Is there any way to check if the device is currently connected to a bluetooth device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

My app is currently in need of a way to know if I could know the users device is currently connected to the any bluetooth device when the application is launched/activity is launched/resumed/paused， Ive tried ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED but it can't check device connection state when the device is already connected before the activity is launched or connected outside the activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getbondeddevices() not returning paired bluetooth devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975199/getbondeddevices-not-returning-paired-bluetooth-devices)

Comment: I want to know if any connected device is present but not only paired device